# how would I catch a JavaScript warning in a try / catch statement?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I need to be able to check if I can close the current page, however since it returns the warning "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them." It wont be caught by a try/catch statement because it isn't an "error". Is there any way I can get around this?

```
function attemptToClose() {
  try {
     window.close();
  }
  catch(err) {
    //do something different
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't. thats managed by the browser

Comment: What's the problem with warnings being logged in the devtools? Does the code work as expected or not?

Comment: Maybe check `window.opener`.

Comment: @Bergi i want to adjust some code based on some specific `OTS parsing error` warnings to not only notify the user but control the actual output of the script instead of leaving it up to the browser. is it still impossible to detect warnings?

Comment: @oldboy I don't know what OTS refers to, but please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about those; this question is about the "close only windows opened by same script" warnings. Btw these console warnings are not meant for the user anyway, they're meant for the developer.

Comment: im assuming it the `OT` in `OTS` means `OpenType`. maybe `OpenType Script`? oh, my question is related to the question in the title of the question lol

Comment: @Bergi (forgot to tag you in my prev response) anyways, found some info about it. OTS stands for [OpenType Sanitize](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots). i posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929778/detecting-warnings-from-new-fontface-load) about it

Comment: @oldboy Thanks for the separate question. Given you are working with electron, not a web browser, the solution would be quite different

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly `window.close();` can only close pages open by itself aka `window.open();`.
This might be a security prevention method so that websites do not take control of your browsers.

Try initiating the page with `window.open();` then try using the `window.close();`.

Hope this solves it!

Comment: I was trying to find a work around to using window.open(), since I would want to close a tab that is opened by a exe file. I guess I can just move the code to close it to the c++ as well. Thank you for trying to help!