# Detecting Warnings from new FontFace.load() / document.fonts.add()

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, warnings, font-face

I am building an electron app that allows users to provide paths to local font files. Sometimes warnings are cast when loading these font files dynamically, in which case the local fonts are not applied and a default font is displayed instead. I am hoping to be able to detect these warnings so that I can notify the user by rendering something on-screen. **Is it therefore possible to detect these warnings?**

***To be clear, these are not errors thrown by the promise, but warnings. Notably, OTS stands for [OpenType Sanitize](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots).***

`Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>`

`OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 333319`

`OTS parsing error: CFF : Failed to parse table`

`OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1097032549`

`OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header`

`OTS parsing error: OS/2: Failed to parse table`

`OTS parsing error: maxp: Failed to parse table`

`OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to parse table`

`OTS parsing error: head: Failed to parse table`

`OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT`

```
  fontList.forEach(font => {
    const
      ff = new FontFace(`_${font.newFileName}`, `url('${font.newFilePath.replace(/\\/g, '/')}')`),
      fontItem = fontItemTemplate.content.cloneNode(true),
      fontNameElement = fontItem.querySelector('.font-name')
    ff.load()
    .then(
      () => {

        document.fonts.add(ff)

        // SOMEHOW DETECT WARNINGS
        // TO DISPLAY NOTIFICATION

        fontNameElement.style.setProperty('--font-family', `_${font.newFileName}`)
        fontNameElement.style.fontFamily = 'var(--font-family)'
        fontNameElement.textContent = font.ogFileName
        middle.appendChild(fontItem)
      },
      error => {
        console.error('ERROR LOADING @FONT-FACE:', error)
      }
    )
  })
```

Comment: It seems that this is an oversight in the DOM spec, it doesn't seem to be currently possible: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/852

Comment: However, you can `fetch()` the file yourself, parse it yourself [using some library](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=opentype), then throw the relevant errors or pass the blob to the `FontFace` constructor.

Comment: And maybe you don't even need to parse it, just checking whether the file is served from the URL with the expected mime type might already catch most of the problems people experience.